# Parse.com conditionally update a row

Tags: parse-platform

I am new to Parse.com. I have enabled saveEventually in my code as follows

```
 ParseObject gameScore = new ParseObject(PARSE_TABLE_NAME);
                            gameScore.put("userState", jsonUserState);
                            gameScore.put("User", currentUser);
                            gameScore.put("Tag", Tag);
                            gameScore.saveEventually();
```

Now what i want is that before saving this code, if the same tag exists i dont want to add the row to Parse cloud. If it does not exist i want to add this. The way things are structured, this code will probably run on a device that is offline, so i cannot query this here.

```
Parse.Cloud.beforeSave("GameScore", function(request, response) {

});
```

can i use the above function to check if the tag exists and if not then update the field, otherwise leave it.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can. Just query for the tag in the beforeSave, and if it exists return `response.error("Error message here")`. If the tag isn't there, return `response.success()`.

A very similar example exists in the [documentation](https://parse.com/docs/cloud_code_guide#functions-onsave).